# What does --prefix in ./configure script do when building a software in Linux?

Tags: unix, centos7

I'd install a software in Linux from source code. I already downloaded the source code from the git project then the next step is to install the libraries needed for running the software.
Let's say the source code is found in a folder called `Main_Folder` and the library is found in another folder `Lib_Folder`. Let's go to latter folder and running the `configure.sh` script to configure the program, so my question is the following:
 In the `./configure` command line there is an option called `--prefix{}` which should specify a given path, I'd know which path I have to put here ? is it the path to the main software or whatever ?

Comment: Welcome to `SO`. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What software are you trying to install ? What issue you are facing ?

Comment: I'm trying to install CP2K in our cluster. (kind of electronic structure method)

Comment: Try using this script --> https://github.com/cp2k/cp2k/blob/master/tools/toolchain/install_cp2k_toolchain.sh

Comment: I did that before but It didn't work.

Comment: How can anyone help without knowing what issue you are facing ? Please edit your post and add error message.

Answer (score 0):

In general `--prefix` defines target installation directory where built software will be installed when running `make install`.

For example if you run `./configure=/opt` executables will be installed in `/opt/bin`, libraries in `/opt/lib`, man pages in `/opt/man/` etc.

See [autoconf --prefix documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#Default-Prefix).